# Magento 2 admin not working

Tags: magento2, admin, login

On entering admin username/password - getting error - "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."
And some time big url http://www,-------------.com/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/286310d2d38e6d6df2c4f0df1663f3b2f2c61a23ba178174c86f746588d34b4b/
This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Unlock admin account

try command in case the account is locked

```
/bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>
```

or go to Magento 2 root folder and type

```
magento admin:user:unlock <username>
```

Example

```
magento admin:user:unlock admin
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to create new using ssh and login with new user

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-admin' --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Assigned is selected as **YES** under User Role tab while creating new admin user.

[image: Make sure Assigned is selected as **YES**]

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file path and \vendor\zendframework\zend-crypt\src\Utils.php and echo $expected and $actual variable and check both are same or not if both variable are not match then change line no 35

**if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return hash_equals($expected, $actual); }**

To

**if (function_exists('hash_equals')) { return true; }**

for direct access to magento admin with any password and then change password and revert back code changes

This solution work for me

Comment: This solution works with me 2.1.1, Thanks alot.

Comment: @abhilash lohar: you should *never* change files in the `vendor/` folder. It will disappear next time you run `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac ox terminal. Please follow the steps to unlock user (in my case it is **khowal**)

1. ssh user@yourdomainname
2. cd public_html
3. php bin/magento admin:user:unlock khowal

After you issues the 3rd command  php bin/magento admin:user:unlock khowal, you should see the below message, [Don't forgot to replace user name]

The user account "khowal" has been unlocked